# Bottom Navigation Bar Android Selected color not change

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have created a bottom navigation bar, it contains three menus. When i click the second menu the background selected color does not change, same for third menu. But when i click again it changes.

I did not try any other ways to correct it.

Comment: Can you share material or code to support your question?